# Cloud notebooks not loading/creating/opening

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I'm not sure if this is right place to ask, but I can't come up with better one for now.

Issue is, when I want to open wolfram cloud notebook (clicking "go to code" link in wolfram alpha answers, or "create new Notebook" [here](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/)), it doesn't work. Frame (top bar and central area split into two parts, one for input one for I forgot what) appears, flashes and then disappears, leaving window white without any input prompt. Only thing left is a moving blue bar on top, in style of modern loading bars indicating that program is working without giving any time estimate.

Issue happens on Firefox 56 (win7) and 63(win7 and win10), does not appear version dependant.

Help please.

Comment: Please contact WRI Support.

Comment: I have the same issue on Chrome and Firefox since yesterday.

Comment: Same problem here (Dec 22 2018)
Firefox, Chrome, MSIE

Comment: @Klangen Been a while, but, if you still have issues, try answer I just posted.

Comment: @David Been a while, but, if you still have issues, try answer I just posted.

Comment: Same problem on safari & firefox using macOS. The js console reports 3 warnings about unused stylesheets and, more worryingly, the error `TypeError: m().reportVisit is not a function. (In 'm().reportVisit(e)', 'm().reportVisit' is undefined)`. It just seems to be some analytics function but I'm worried it could be part of a larger function which was terminated when this crashed... In particular, the stack frame includes one called "render". Should I edit the question to add this new information?

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this as answer, because this did resolve the issue in at least one computer, even though it makes little sense. I'll test it on another problematic machine and browser, if "fix" works, I'm going to mark this as accepted.

It turns out, problem was somehow related to AdBlock Plus, despite AdBlock icon being greyed out on Wolfram Cloud, details shown after clicking AdBlock icon even said it's offline on Wolfram Cloud. Enabling (!) AdBlock fixed the issue and now, Wolfram Cloud works properly no matter if Wolfram Cloud is whitelisted or not.

EDIT: Welp. It's not universal. Got same issue on another machine, which has freshly installed Win10/Firefox(64.0.2 64bit), everything's so fresh that it never even had AdBlock installed. Installing AdBlock to meddle with it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the URL you are using ([lab.open.wolframcloud.com](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/)) is a deprecated one. It doesn't work for me either. But when I instead go to the URL [develop.wolframcloud.com](https://develop.wolframcloud.com), everything works just fine.